# XSLT 1.0 String split template not working

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT and am having an issue with templates. I have an input xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node>
<PHASE1_TYPE>LEFT,TOP</PHASE1_TYPE>
<PHASE1_HOL>TOK,ZUR,VIN</PHASE1_HOL>
<PHASE2_TYPE>RIGHT,BOTTOM</PHASE2_TYPE>
<PHASE2_HOL>CHF</PHASE2_HOL>
</Node>
```

My xslt is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template  name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
            <Holiday>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </Holiday>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Holiday>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                    substring-before($text, $separator))"/>
            </Holiday>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" 
                  select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Document>
 <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" 
  namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    >C:/usr/NONMAR~1/Output.xsd</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:for-each select="Node">
<Deal>

<DealType>
<xsl:value-of select="string(PHASE1_TYPE)"/>
</DealType>
<Holidays>

<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="string(PHASE1_HOL)"/>
<xsl:with-param name="separator" select="','"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</Holidays>
</Deal>
<Deal>

<DealType>
<xsl:value-of select="string(PHASE2_TYPE)"/>
</DealType>

<Holidays>
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
<xsl:with-param name="text" select="string(PHASE2_HOL)"/>
<xsl:with-param name="separator" select="','"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</Holidays>
</Deal>
</xsl:for-each>
</Document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After transformation, my output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:/usr/NONMAR~1/Output.xsd">

<Deal>
<DealType>LEFT,TOP</DealType>
<Holidays>
<Holiday/>
</Holidays>
</Deal>

<Deal>
<DealType>RIGHT,BOTTOM</DealType>
<Holidays>
<Holiday/>
</Holidays>
</Deal>

</Document>
```

but the expected Output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:/usr/NONMAR~1/Output.xsd">

<Deal>
<DealType>LEFT,TOP</DealType>
<Holidays>
<Holiday>TOK</Holiday>
<Holiday>ZUR</Holiday>
<Holiday>VIN</Holiday>
</Holidays>
</Deal>

<Deal>
<DealType>RIGHT,BOTTOM</DealType>
<Holidays>
<Holiday>CHF</Holiday>
</Holidays>
</Deal>

</Document>
```

I am using xslt 1.0 and do not want to use third party functions like EXSLT. Again, I am new to XSLT and do not have time right now to learn it. Would really appreciate if someone can tell me why this template is not working properly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's impossible to tell, from the information you provide.

On the plus side, you've taken some effort to cut your stylesheet and your sample input down in size and simplify them.  That's good; I wish more new Stack Overflow users knew to do that.

On the minus side, the code you provide doesn't produce the output you show from the input you show.  First of all, it's not well-formed; the end-tag for an xsl:for-each has gotten left out.  And then that for-each, in the template for the document node, uses `select="Node"`, which looks for elements named Node which are children of the document node -- but in your input, the only element child of the document node is named 'Root'.  And your tokenization template wraps the individual tokens in `item` elements, instead of `Holiday` elements.  When the first two slips are fixed, the stylesheet appears to produce the output you desire (modulo the Holiday/item issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
              "C:/usr/NONMAR~1/Output.xsd">
  <Deal>
    <DealType>LEFT,TOP</DealType>
    <Holidays>
      <item>TOK</item>
      <item>ZUR</item>
      <item>VIN</item>
    </Holidays>
  </Deal>
  <Deal>
    <DealType>RIGHT,BOTTOM</DealType>
    <Holidays>
      <item>CHF</item>
    </Holidays>
  </Deal>
</Document>
```

Comment: Thanks CMSM. I apologize for not checking my input code completely. I have fixed it now. I have trimmed down my code to only include the problem areas. In my actual code, I am using 5 other templates and they all work fine. The posted template is causing issues by only displaying <Holiday/> instead of with values.

Comment: I have fixed a bug in the xslt and the template is working as expected. We can close this thread. Thanks for the help.